# Playframework 2 : Expressions in conf/routes possible?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

Is there way to include expressions in *conf/routes*, so i do not have to create new controller for such simple actions?

```
GET /:id/:secret  controllers.Default.redirect(to=id+"/edit?secret="+secret)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you really only need one route and one action method to accomplish what, I think, you're wanting.

**conf/routes**

```
GET /redirect/:id/:secret   controllers.Default.redirect(id:String, secret:String)
```

**Default.java**

```
public static Result redirect(String id, String secret)
{
  return redirect(id + "/edit?secret=" + secret);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look to route's types in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaRouting), most probably you can use ie  ***Dynamic parts spanning several /***.

For an example this one will pass everything after `/redirect/` as a single String:

```
GET  /redirect/*targetPath   controllers.Application.redirectTo(targetPath:String)
```

so in request `http://localhost/redirect/new/location/123?secret=foo&something=bar` its value will be: `new/location/123?secret=foo&something=bar`

Optionally you don't need even to declare your `secret` as a route param, as you can use ie. `bindFromRequest()` method for checking if it exist. (so it can be compared to `$_GET['secret']` in `PHP`